# How do I implement an image viewer and rotator?

Tags: images

I am currently in the process of redesigning a WordPress site. There is a thing I want to have on my new site that I see all the time on other sites.

Take a look at http://muvere.com/ and http://www.ibm.com/us/en/. Notice the image viewer and rotator thingie - is there a name for this thing? It is some kind of mechanism for displaying a variety of images and text, and automatically rotating between them.

It seems to me like this would be an easy thing to implement in my web site. Is there a plugin that makes it easy? It's hard for me to research this topic on my own because I don't know what the thing that I want is called.

Comment: This is off-topic per the [FAQ]. Research on jQuery community at Google Plus.

Comment: I don't know if it is completely off-topic.  There are plenty of WordPress plugins that deal with sliders and if you don't even know what it is called research will be limiting.

Comment: I found what I was looking for - http://slidedeck.com/

Comment: @helgatheviking, plugin/theme recommendations was [made off-topic some months ago](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/12615)...

Comment: @brasofilo Touché. Is there a place where you should ask that kind of thing?

Comment: @helgatheviking, [so] seems more permissive about it, but the whole ["recommendation"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=recommendation+is%3Aquestion) thing is kind of unwelcomed... I like Google+ WP communities, as well as the jQuery/PHP/HTML5 ones. Cool things going on over there ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of slider plugins.  Some are just jQuery plugins that would require you to create your own code for, but off the top of my head I know that [Nivo](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/) and [Woo](http://www.woothemes.com/products/wooslider/) both make fully-integrated slider plugins where you can control the control from within WordPress.

Both release their jQuery plugin script, free of charge and I have used them both extensively and have found them both to be easy to work with from my perspective as a developer.  Because I write my own code, I haven't needed to test their full WordPress plugins which are premium products and come with a cost.  I can't speak for the WordPress side of things, but if they're anything like the jQuery side of things I would expect high quality.  There might be free options in the WordPress repo if you search for slider plugins.

The Flexslider is responsive and is better suited to responsive designs, whereas the Nivo slider has a lot more transitions to chose from.